# Get Autoscaling groups of ElasticBeanstalk environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

How can I get a list of ElasticBeanstalk environments together with their AutoScaling groups information via SDK?

I want to do an API for users to scale down the instances to 0, to save costs after office hours.

I could use `DescribeEnvironments` then for each environment call `DescribeEnvironmentResources` but I think this is less ideal? I am making `O(n)` calls to `DescribeEnvironmentResources` which maybe slow?

Comment: What language sdk do you want to use?

Comment: @JordanStewart I use Go currently. But I think the idea should be applicable to any language?

Comment: Yeah, I think all the SDKs use the same underlying REST API. The Go SDK should have similar functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to describe the ElasticBeanstalk environments, and get the names of the auto-scaling groups from the response. Then query the information for the auto-scaling groups. You will probably want to change the desired capacity of the Autoscaling group, from here. You should be able to put that into an API for users.

With the ruby sdk:
Get information about the ElasticBeanStalk:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ElasticBeanstalk/Client.html#describe_environment_resources-instance_method

Get information about the AutoScaling group:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/AutoScaling/Client.html#describe_auto_scaling_groups-instance_method

Set desired capacity of the AutoScaling group:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/AutoScaling/Client.html#set_desired_capacity-instance_method

The code should look something like:

```
elasticbeanstalk = Aws::ElasticBeanstalk::Client.new(
    region: region_name,
    credentials: credentials,
)

# assuming you know the environment names    
resp = elasticbeanstalk.describe_environment_resources({
  environment_name: "my-env", 
})

auto_scaling_groups_array = resp.to_hash['environment_resources']['auto_scaling_groups']
# auto_scaling_groups_array[0].name should give the name of the first autoscaling group


autoscaling = Aws::AutoScaling::Client.new(
  region: region_name,
  credentials: credentials,
  # ...
)

# get the resources of an AutoScaling Group, you probably want to do this for each group
resp = autoscaling.describe_auto_scaling_groups({
  auto_scaling_group_names: [
   "my-auto-scaling-group", # or auto_scaling_groups_array[0].name
  ]
})

# set the desired capacity, you probably want to do this for each group
resp = autoscaling.set_desired_capacity({
  auto_scaling_group_name: "my-auto-scaling-group", # or auto_scaling_groups_array[0].name
  desired_capacity: 2, 
  honor_cooldown: true, 
})
```

You probably want to do this for each region. I haven't tested this. I hope that helps.

Comment: I find that I seem to be able to by pass the 1st step to get all elastic beanstalk environment by querying autoscaling groups directly instead. From there I know which environment it is by the tag `elasticbeanstalk:environment-id`. Not sure if this is reliable

Comment: I think that assumes every elasticbeanstalk environment has at least one Autoscaling group attached. That might be fine for your usecase, if you don't need all the elasticbeanstalk environments.

Comment: Is there any case where an EB environment does not have an auto scaling group? I notice even single instance EB has auto scaling groups

Comment: You can configure EB to use a single instance. The default for EB is a load balancer, and an autoscaling group. So it is an assumption to rely on an EB having an autoscaling group. It might be okay to make this assumption. For your particular use-cases you want to scale down instances, so you are relying on having an autoscaling group attached.

Comment: Just wondering for an EB environment without an autoscaling group, do I just terminate that instance then? EB will not start a new one in this case?

Comment: I would recommend just using an autoscaling group with an EB. And use that as a standard setup, and knowing if its constraints. And I would write that down as a precondition. It will make the system simpler. With the single instance, you could stop the instance. I wouldn't recommend terminated the instance. That generally deletes it, and you would have to create a new one.